# How can I add strings in c programming?

Tags: c, sorting

Above all, the program will get a number of students and a number (card) that each student draws.
for example, input would be 2 lines:

```
5
0 1 1 3 2
```

And then the output would be:

```
4 2 5 3 1
```

There are 5 students called `1,2,3,4,5.` (5 students exist in room "A" and enter room "B" in sequence)

- Firstly: number 1 student enter room and do nothing.
- Secondly: number 2 student can subtract numbers 0, 1. If he draw number 1, line order would be `2 1`. Else, line order would be `1 2`. (there is a space-bar between student) it means the number he chose would be number of people he can go ahead.
- Thirdly, number 3 student can subtract number 0,1,2 (Suppose that number 2 student choose 1), if number 3 student choose number 2, line order would be `3 2 1`. In this way, why I am wrong with  `c = "2 1";` which is line 27,
  and is there a better way to solve it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i;
    printf("How many students??\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int a[n], b[n];
    char c[100];
    char e[100];
    char f[100];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        b[i] = i + 1;
    }
    if (n > 100 || n <= 0) {
        // printf("Students number is incorrect\n");
        main();
    }
    else {
        //printf("Write down number card each student get\n");
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            scanf("%d", a[i]);
        }

        if (a[1] == 1) { //number 2 students enter
            **c = "2 1";
            **
        }
        else {
            c = "1 2";
        }

        if (a[2] == 2) //number 3 student enter
        {
            d = "3 " + c;
        }
        else if (a[2] == 1) {
            d = c[0] + " 3 " + c[2];
        }
        else {
            d = c[0] + " " + c[2] + " 3";
        }
        if (a[3] == 3) // number 3 student enter
        {
            e = "4 " + d;
        }
        else if (a[3] == 2) {
            e = d[0] + " 4" + d[2] + d[3] + d[4]
        }
        else if (a[3] == 1) {
            e = d[0] + " " + d[2] + " 4" + " " + d[4];
        }
        else {
            e = d[0] + " " + d[2] + " " + d[4] + " 4"
        }
        if (a[4] == 4) {
            f = "5" + e;
        }
        if (a[4] == 3) {
            f = e[0] + " 5" + e[2] + " " + e[4] + " " + e[6];
        }
        else if (a[4] == 2) {
            f = e[0] + " " + e[2] + " 5" + " " + e[4] + " " + e[6];
        }
        else if (a[4] == 1) {
            f = e[0] + " " + e[2] + " " + e[4] + " 5" + " " + e[6];
        }
        else {
            f = e[0] + " " + e[2] + " " + e[4] + " " + e[6] + " 5";
        }

        printf("%s", f);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]". Then come back, [edit] your question, and show us what you learned from your own effort to tackle the issue, and where you stumble. -- You have a good C book or tutorial, haven't you? Look up "string concatenating".

Comment: You don't need strings for this problem.  Use ints.  To answer your question,  a C string is an array, so cannot be assigned.